# Datatables: Changing row color depending on a cell

Tags: php, jquery, css, datatables

I´m trying to change the row color depending on a value, for a server side loaded datatable, but it's not working. I'm using a code like this one on my javascript:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
     'bServerSide': true,
     'bProcessing': true,
     'sAjaxSource': 'datatables/my_ajax.php',
     'iDisplayLength': 50,
     "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
     "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) {
         for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aoData.length; i < iLen; i++) {
             if (jQuery.inArray(oSettings.aoData[i]._aData[2], food_types) != -1) {
                 oSettings.aoData[i].nTr.className = "myClass";
             }
         }
     },
```

myClass looks like:

```
.myClass{ 
    background-color: red;
}

.myClass td {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

So, basically when the second `<td>` of each row has a value that appears on the food types array, the class should be changed to myClass. This part is working (I can see with firebug that the class has changed), however I cannot see the change (I don't see the row turning to red background). What am I missing? Also, is this a good approach or a cleaner way would be to change the color from ajax directly? If so, how?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell with this little information about the context (i.e. the rest of the page and CSS file). Do you have it live somewhere?

Comment: Any reason you need to do this with jQuery instead of just using an if statement when generating the table?

Comment: @RickCalder do you know what datatables is?

Comment: You can do this with CSS only!

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css3-zebra-striping-a-table/

Comment: will take a look, looks interesting, though not sure if it would be good on this case, since it's a bit more complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your dataTable's CSS wrapper is overwriting your style .. Maybe that the reason you do not see the change in the backgroundcolor..

Looks like you need to change the class on which it is being applied..

Maybe more in these terms

```
table.display.myClass 
{

 background-color: red !important
}

table.display.myClass td
{

 background-color: red !important
}
```

More like guessing the wrapper as i have no idea about the exact classes being applied by the datatables plugin..

Comment: how so? can you please give me more details, what do you mean with 'change the class on which it is being applied'?

Comment: Excellent Sushanth! Thank you! I'll accept your answer when they let me (in like 6 mins).